# How was physics taught in the past (e.g., in the 19th century)?

Tags: physics, education

Were there physics teaching aids used in the past? Or did professors just basically follow the textbook the students read?

In other words: How was physics was taught in the past (e.g., in the 19th century)?

Comment: It was taught in the same way as today. Lectures and experiment demonstrations.

Comment: So when did student labs come it?  Not only physics, but chemistry, biology, etc.?